# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'dataframe' How can i solve this?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

import pandas as pd

data={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan'],'Age':[23,22,21,24]}

df=pd.dataframe(data)

df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dataframe should be in pascal case format not in small letters. See the documentation of pandas.
Eg.  pd.DataFrame(data)